# css page minimum height

Tags: html, css

Can anyone explain to me why my `HTML` page is not filling the height of the screen?  I tried to set the `min-height` in the css but it's not really affecting anything.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9yFKn/

Comment: You should refactor to avoid using the `*` selector, you don't need to apply your font family to every element in the DOM. Also, a duplicate of a very frequently asked question, please try to search before asking in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're not accounting for the height of the body.

Just add

```
body{
    height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9yFKn/1/

Comment: The reason this is necessary is that like other DOM elements, body doesn't have a preset height property. However what it does have is padding, which you may need to set to zero depending on how _fully_ you want to occupy space.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution :

```
  html, body {    height: 100%;    }
```

but it just a solution you need to understand why is happened , this happened because your element is a block level element which wrap up your whole content width and height width as a 100% but this is not the case with height you need to specify the related to content to give a height in percentages like as above body has given 100%

[here is the solution too](http://jsfiddle.net/RRktN/)